# Using the SharePoint REST API to update a list item

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-rest-api

I am attempting to [update a list item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest#update-list-item) using the SharePoint REST API but am encountering the following error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <m:code>-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException</m:code>
    <m:message xml:lang="en-US">The expression "web/lists/GetByTitle('Drop Off Library')/items("http:/example.com/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/DropOffLibrary/b.txt')")" is not valid.</m:message>
</m:error>
```

After adding the file, I receive the following response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<entry xml:base="http://example.com/_api/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
    <id>http://example.com/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/DropOffLibrary/b.txt')</id>
    <category term="SP.File" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <link rel="edit" href="Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/DropOffLibrary/b.txt')" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Author" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="Author" href="Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/DropOffLibrary/b.txt')/Author" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/CheckedOutByUser" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="CheckedOutByUser" href="Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/DropOffLibrary/b.txt')/CheckedOutByUser" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/EffectiveInformationRightsManagementSettings" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="EffectiveInformationRightsManagementSettings" href="Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/DropOffLibrary/b.txt')/EffectiveInformationRightsManagementSettings" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/InformationRightsManagementSettings" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="InformationRightsManagementSettings" href="Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/DropOffLibrary/b.txt')/InformationRightsManagementSettings" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/ListItemAllFields" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="ListItemAllFields" href="Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/DropOffLibrary/b.txt')/ListItemAllFields" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/LockedByUser" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="LockedByUser" href="Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/DropOffLibrary/b.txt')/LockedByUser" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/ModifiedBy" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="ModifiedBy" href="Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/DropOffLibrary/b.txt')/ModifiedBy" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Properties" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="Properties" href="Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/DropOffLibrary/b.txt')/Properties" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Versions" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Versions" href="Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/DropOffLibrary/b.txt')/Versions" />
    <title />
    <updated>2019-01-11T14:47:13Z</updated>
    <author>
        <name />
    </author>
    <content type="application/xml">
        <m:properties>
            <d:CheckInComment></d:CheckInComment>
            <d:CheckOutType m:type="Edm.Int32">0</d:CheckOutType>
            <d:ContentTag>{2BDD4E2D-79C8-4F6B-8DD7-AC745D9360A8},1,1</d:ContentTag>
            <d:CustomizedPageStatus m:type="Edm.Int32">0</d:CustomizedPageStatus>
            <d:ETag>"{2BDD4E2D-79C8-4F6B-8DD7-AC745D9360A8},1"</d:ETag>
            <d:Exists m:type="Edm.Boolean">true</d:Exists>
            <d:IrmEnabled m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:IrmEnabled>
            <d:Length m:type="Edm.Int64">4</d:Length>
            <d:Level m:type="Edm.Byte">255</d:Level>
            <d:LinkingUrl></d:LinkingUrl>
            <d:MajorVersion m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:MajorVersion>
            <d:MinorVersion m:type="Edm.Int32">0</d:MinorVersion>
            <d:Name>b.txt</d:Name>
            <d:ServerRelativeUrl>/DropOffLibrary/b.txt</d:ServerRelativeUrl>
            <d:TimeCreated m:type="Edm.DateTime">2019-01-11T14:47:13Z</d:TimeCreated>
            <d:TimeLastModified m:type="Edm.DateTime">2019-01-11T14:47:13Z</d:TimeLastModified>
            <d:Title m:null="true" />
            <d:UIVersion m:type="Edm.Int32">512</d:UIVersion>
            <d:UIVersionLabel>1.0</d:UIVersionLabel>
            <d:UniqueId m:type="Edm.Guid">2bdd4e2d-79c8-4f6b-8dd7-ac745d9360a8</d:UniqueId>
        </m:properties>
    </content>
</entry>
```

My assumption here is that the item id is either the value of the `<id>` tag or the value of the `<UniqueId>` tag, but neither have worked.

Answer (score 0):

First you should set `Accept` header to `application/json` for your request so the result will be a bit better to read.

`Item ID` is an incremental integer in the library. You can add column `ID` to a view in the library to see the value for each file. From some reason this `ID` is missing in the response you get when the file is uploaded.

To get item by ID (best option) use:

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Drop Off Library')/items(1)
```

To get item by server relative url (also fine option) use:

```
/_api/web/getFileByServerRelativeUrl('/DropOffLibrary/b.txt')
```

`UniqueId` is a guid which cannot be easily used for querying the item. You would have to use `$filter` parameter, but it is not optimal due to performace impact.

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Drop Off Library')/items?$filter=GUID eq guid'2bdd4e2d-79c8-4f6b-8dd7-ac745d9360a8'
```